# Should I add a method for each action you can do on a page using Page Object Model in test framework?

Tags: automated-tests, pageobjects

I have a page object framework and would like to reduce the amount of code in each class. Each class has a function that takes in test data and determines what to do with it (enter data on page, click something etc.) I have @FindBy for the web elements I will be using. My question is, should I also have a method for each action that I will do on each web element?

For example, I have a web element for entering a username, should I have a corresponding method called enterUsername(String username)?

Currently I feel like this will cause bloat and there is no reason the test can't operate on WebElements themselves but I am looking for examples that would push my decision one way or the other.

N/A

```
public class Page1
@FindBy
WebElement userName;

public void enterUsername(String s) {
    username.sendKeys(s);
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    //go to page1
    page1.userName.sendKeys("username123");
}
```

Results should be the same either way. What I am interested in is maintainability and cleanliness of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go for option 1 (I would add [clear()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#clear--) function call before typing just in case)

With regards to the "each action" - you should create a method for each user scenario for the user visiting this or that page you're going to automate.

The main idea of the [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) is to provide an [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)#Abstraction_in_object_oriented_programming) layer between your test logic and the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) of the application under test

So your test would look like:

```
@Test
public void loginUsingCorrectCredentials() {
    page1.enterCredentials("admin", "secret");
    Assert.assertTrue(page1.isUserLoggedIn(),"Failed to login");
}

@Test
public void loginUsingInCorrectCredentials() {
    page1.enterCredentials("admin", "badpassword");
    Assert.assertFalse(page1.isUserLoggedIn(),"Failed to login");
}
```

So keep in mind 2 main principles:

1. Your tests should exactly represent real life [business use cases](https://sceweb.uhcl.edu/helm/RationalUnifiedProcess/process/modguide/md_bucm.htm) and the functions you create at the page should match all scenarios you're going to cover
2. Keep UI-related stuff in Page Objects and Test Logic in test code, to wit no WebElements in test cases and no Assertions in Page Objects